# Can I use MKT capacitor instead of MKP in the following topology?

Tags: capacitor, emc, emi-filtering, power-factor-correction

The following topology is a boost PFC designed by STMicroelectronics. The input capacitor (C1) is an MKP one. Can I use an MKT (fig2) or polyester (fig3) capacitor instead of that?

[image: fig1]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you research the difference between them? Do you know what exactly capacitor properties are relevant in this case?

Comment: What about reading and comparing both datasheets? Both types should be rated for 630 V, may be some derating due to increased temperature.